# Why do most Spring applications root level folders always seem to follow the com/company naming convention?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, naming-conventions

I am asking whether there is a factual reason/standard behind this, as I haven't been able to find anything concrete on this. I am not asking for people's opinions.

It seems like, at first glance, that for Spring projects attached to some sort of web entity, like say `company.com`, the corresponding package naming goes `<domain_extension>/<second_level_domain_name>`.

Is there any truth to this?

Comment: Because that's how packages are named in the Java ecosystem?

Comment: yes @jonrsharpe